# showing Omega(n log(n)) bound on the number of comparisons needed by a sorting algo that divides n elements into n/k subsequences

Tags: sorting, asymptotic-complexity, proof, lower-bound

Suppose that you are given a sequence of n elements to sort. The input sequence consists of n/k subsequences, each containing k elements. The elements in a given subsequence are all smaller than the elements in the succeeding subsequence and larger than the elements in the preceding subsequence. Thus, all that is needed to sort the whole sequence of length n is to sort the k elements in each of the n/k subsequences. Show an Ω(n lg k) lower bound on the number of comparisons needed to solve this variant of the sorting algorithm. (Hint: It is not rigorous to simply combine the lower bounds for the individual subsequences.)

need a hint, not really sure how to approach this. In my book we cover the decision tree model which makes sense to me.

Comment: The hint seems confusing. It appears that the assumption is that each subsequence can be sorted with Ω(k lg k) comparisons, and since there are  n/k subsequences, the total number of comparisons would be n/k Ω(k lg k) = Ω(n lg k) , but the proof requires more than this?